# Creating a simple jQuery sliding effect when hovering over an image

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

How can I create this simple jQuery effect when someone hovers over an image on my page?

A JSFiddle example [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFsE/).

[image]

I want when someone enters the image or any part of the box, the text area should expand revealing more details.

On mouse leave, the text area should shrink and only allow the image to be visible.

Here is my attempt:

```
$("#free-roster .roster-container .champion").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find(".info").animate({ width: "116px" }, 400);
});

$("#free-roster .roster-container .champion").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find(".info").animate({ width: "0px" }, 400);
});
```

Comment: What is this `$("#.champion")`. Are you grabbing a class or id?

Comment: I don't why it copied that way, fixed it. There's a live example to see what I'm talking about, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery works for me:

```
$("#free-roster .roster-container .champion").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find(".info").animate({ width: "116px" }, 400);
});

$("#free-roster .roster-container .champion").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find(".info").animate({ width: "0px" }, 400);
});

$("#free-roster .roster-container .champion").mouseleave();
```

In your CSS add:

```
color: white;
```

to:

```
#free-roster .roster-container .champion .info
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EFsE/1/

Comment: The problem with this is that `.info` is being attached to an inline css style: `display:block` which is causing it to appear below the image. I want it to stretch the gray container box to fit the text. Any other ideas?

Comment: In IE9 and Firefox 11 the text appears next to the image as shown in your screenshot above.  I don't have older browsers to look at but I've had some luck in the past with display: inline-block